How to get dialogflow analytics data
So what I am trying is, I have a dialogflow cx phone-gateway setup and a react project and python backend. What I'm trying is when I load the frontend page, it calls the backend which gets the analytics data from dialogflow and gives it to react js which uses react flow library to render the flow and analytics data on these flows/pages.
By Analytics data I mean: Which flows have been hit the most during a call, which flows have missed, which intents/questions were asked the most and where did the user end the call mostly etc.
What I have tried is, call a webhook on each page and record the user journey in the db. Then when the page loads, I get the dialogflow cx flows and pages in python,

def get_dialogflow_flows(parent):
    try:
        print("Flows and Intents called")
        os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = current_app.config['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']

        flow_client = dialogflowcx.FlowsClient()
        page_client = dialogflowcx.PagesClient()

        start_time = time.time()

        flows = flow_client.list_flows(parent=parent)
        print("Flows Fetched --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
        flow_data = []

        # start_time = time.time()
        for flow in flows:
            # Fetch pages for each flow using PagesClient
            pages = list(page_client.list_pages(parent=flow.name))
            flow_pages = []

            for page in pages:
                # Get full page details including transition routes
                page_details = page_client.get_page(name=page.name)
                transitions = []

                for route in page_details.transition_routes:
                    transitions.append({
                        'target_page': route.target_page,
                        'target_flow': route.target_flow,
                        'condition': route.condition
                    })

                flow_pages.append({
                    'page_name': page.display_name,
                    'page_id': page.name,
                    'transitions': transitions  # Include transition routes
                })

            flow_data.append({
                'flow': flow.display_name,
                'flow_id': flow.name,
                'pages': flow_pages
            })

        # print("Second --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
        return make_response(message="Data fetched successfully", success=True, data=flow_data, status=200)
    except Exception as e:
        current_app.logger.error(e)
        return make_response(message=str(e), success=False, data=None, status=500)


using this data, I try to render the flow from dialogflow cx console in my react frontend using react flow library. But, doing this is not great because I have to manage webhooks call and database entries for each page/flow.
So, is there a way I can do this better? I know there is analytics page in dialogflow cx console, is there any way I can get that data?

Under Logging and history in Dialogflow public documentations, stated in Interaction logging export to BigQuery, we can export interaction logging to BigQuery. Once configured, all live interaction logging is written to your BigQuery table. This provides you with advanced analysis tools that can help you debug and improve your agent and to discover patterns in conversation data. It has a maximum of 500 turns that can be exported for each conversation.
To configure interaction logging export:

Ensure that interaction logging is enabled.

Follow the BigQuery dataset creation guide to create a dataset. Note the dataset name, as you will need this in the next step.

Follow the BigQuery table creation guide to create a table with a SQL schema definition. Use the following SQL statement for creation:
CREATE TABLE <your_dataset_name>.dialogflow_bigquery_export_data(
  project_id STRING,
  agent_id STRING,
  conversation_name STRING,
  turn_position INTEGER,
  request_time TIMESTAMP,
  language_code STRING,
  request JSON,
  response JSON,
  partial_responses JSON,
  derived_data JSON,
  conversation_signals JSON,
  bot_answer_feedback JSON
);


Configure your agent settings to enable BigQuery export, and to provide the dataset and table names created above.


